# SpeechSynthesizer is silent and terribly robotic over headphones

Tags: c#, windows, audio, text-to-speech

I'm writing a text to speech app. I'm using SpeechSynthesizer. All is great if I use loudspeakers. But as soon as I connect headset, the TTS is too silent and starts to be completely robotic sounding like quality was downgraded at least 1000x.
I tested Windows 'change text to speech settings' and it has same issue. On loudspeaker, it sounds fine and in headset it sounds terribly poor and silent.

Note that I'm sure that my headsets are O.K. because any song from YouTube sounds the same as from loudspeakers.

Anyone experienced this? How it could be resolved?

Comment: On which operating system are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: @georges619 - Windows 10 pro - Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648]

Comment: Since the same issue happens externally to your application, then this question probably is off topic on SO, since it doesn't seem that the code is the issue.  You may wish to ask this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)